# Creating jar from java project which uses jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jar

I have finished my java application using eclipse, with some sql code. I am using oracle database and jdbc connector.

When I am trying to create a jar file it shows me this message: JAR export finished with warnings.

See details for additional information.

```
  Exported with compile warnings: 
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
    Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'C:Users/Grlouk/Downloads/ojdbc6.jar'
```

And when finally I am creating a.exe file from .jar database functions does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: is `ojdbc6.jar` file present in `C:\Users\Grlouk\Downloads` folder?

Comment: I'd copy the Jar file into the project (`lib` folder) and add it as a Jar library (not as an _external_ Jar library!). This way it'll be copied into the exported application Jar file ... BTW: you can only add a Jar library from the project - the file selector with allows to pick a file from `C:Users/Grlouk/Downloads/ojdbc6.jar` will only be opened for external Jar files.

Comment: Trinimon , I have already done it..just the same error.

Comment: @grlouk: but it's an external Jar file (because `C:Users/Grlouk/Downloads` doesn't seem to be your project path). That won't work. External Jars in the _Java Build Path_ have to be available on the target platform. You have to choose _Add Jars_ from the project properties.

Comment: @grlouk: did you use the _Export_, _Java_, _Jar file_ menu? This way it should work ... it did at least with my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the exporter is looking for the JDBC library `ojdbc6.jar` in your `C:\Users\Grlouk\Downloads` folder and finding it missing.

There are a couple of ways to fix this.

1) Find where your `ojdbc6.jar` file is located and put it in `C:\Users\Grlouk\Downloads`

2) Change the classpath to reflect the actual location of `ojdbc6.jar` file, e.g. if you are using the Eclipse IDE you can right click on your project and **Build Path > Configure Build Path...** to open the build path configuration and then under the **Libraries** tab you can manage the libraries, and under the **Order and Export** you can explicitly state which libraries will get exported, you might want to select the `ojdbc6.jar` here if it please you.

Answer (score 0):

Placing jar inside a jar won't work. You have to use it with some third party libraries. Because when you are trying to executing the jar file it tries to search the jar files in the mentioned path. Jar file will not be present in the path so classpath fails. Do it with eclipse by exporting to jar. 
Eclipse will load the jar files on the fly and add it to your classpath.

Comment: I think OP is using Eclipse, but unlike the traditional export, OP is specifically using the Fat Jar plugin.